Is gain scaling when decimating a LPF by D always 1/D?
There is a real lowpass FIR digital filter symmetric in time, the amplitude of which is 1 in the passband in the frequency domain. If it is decimated by 2 in the time domain, the amplitude in the passband becomes about 1/2. If it is decimated by 4 in the time domain, the amplitude in the passband becomes about 1/4. Is this a special case or a general rule? If it is a general rule, how to prove it?


Is this a special case or a general rule?

It's a general rule. It doesn't only apply to lowpass filters (FIR, symmetric, IIR, etc) but to any signal that's bandlimited enough to have negligible aliasing when being down-sampled.

If it is a general rule, how to prove it?

Let's do it for down sampling by 2. It works the same for other integers as well. We assume a signal of $x[n]$ of length $N$ and it's DFT $X[k]$. For $D=2$ being bandlimited simply means
$$X[k] \approx 0, k \ge \frac{N}{2} \tag{1}$$
We'll be using the letter $y$ and $Y$ for sequences of length $M=N/2$. We can define two sequences which contain the even and the odd index samples of $x[n]$
$$y_e[m] = x[2n], y_o = x[2n+1] \tag{2}$$
We can make use the "decimation in time" identify
$$X[k] = Y_e[k] + W_N^kY_o[k] \tag{3}$$
where $W_N^k = e^{-j2\pi k/N}$ is the DFT coefficient of base $N$ and power $k$.
$Y_e$ and $Y_o$ are periodic with $M$ so we can write the second half of the spectrum as
$$X[k+M] = Y_e[k+M] + W_N^{k+M} Y_o[k+M] = Y_e[k] - W_N^k Y_o[k] \tag{4} $$
Now we re-introduce our bandlimit from eq (1) and we get
$$X[k+M] = 0 = Y_e[k] - W_N^k Y_o[k], \; 0 \le k < M \tag{5}$$ which simply turns into
$$Y_e[k] =  W_N^k Y_o[k], \; 0 \le k < M \tag{6} $$
or
$$Y_o[k] =  W_N^{-k} Y_e[k], \; 0 \le k < M \tag{6a} $$
This means that magnitude of spectra of the odd and even samples are identical and the only difference is a linear phase term. This makes intuitively sense: the odd samples are a delayed version of the even samples.
Now for the first half of the original spectrum we have
$$X[k] = Y_e[k] + W_N^kY_o[k], \; 0 \le k < M \tag{7} $$
And if we pop in eq(6a) we get
$$X[k] = Y_e[k] + W_N^k  (W_N^{-k} Y_e[k]) = 2 Y_e[k], \; 0 \le k < M \tag{7} $$
Meaning that the non-zero half of the original spectrum is twice the spectrum of the even sample DFT.

Down-sampling by a factor $D$ means to select every $D$th sample in a discrete time domain waveform.  Decimation is when we precede the down-sampling with a low-pass filter, so I will use the term "down-sample" below for what I believe the OP intends.
Note that we can down-sample the coefficients for FIR low pass filters by factor $D$ as the OP describes as long as the filter cutoff is less than $1/D$ as a fraction of Nyquist. As long as we meet this requirement, and consider the effects of aliasing with finite filter rejection, the gain will always drop by $1/D$.
We can see this from the DC gain of a low pass filter is given by the sum of the coefficients:
$$G_{DC} =\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}c_n$$
(This is easily verified from the convolution summation describing the filter).
If we scale the coefficients by the total sum, the DC gain will be 1.
If we then select every other coefficient, the sum would be 1/2, and similarly if we were to only select every Dth coefficient the sum would go down by $1/D$. This will always occur when the number of coefficients after the decimation is $1/D$ of the number of coefficients we started with and the filter cutoff is less than Nyquist/D. (If not exactly $1/D$ coefficients, the scaling will still be very close to $1/D$.) When we down-sample then the frequency response at the input rate will fold due to aliasing, so if the filter attenuation isn't large enough there will be additional passband distortion to consider.
Consider this example of a half-band filter where every other coefficient is 0 except for the samples adjacent to the center coefficient:

The half-band would be the extreme case of a cut-off less than half than Nyquist so can be down-sampled by two at most. The cutoff of the half-band is approximately Nyquist/2 (hence "half-band"), so this would be the limit of our ability to down-sample the filter and still achieve the same passband response. The DC gain of the filter is normalized to be 1, as verified by summing all the coefficients and confirming the sum is equal to 1. If we down-sample by two such that the zero coefficients are selected, then all the filter coefficients in the down-sampled by two filter will be zero except for the center tap which has a value of 0.5, and thus we would have a flat delay with a gain of 0.5. If we were to offset that by one sample and we would select all the non-zero coefficients, except for the center coefficient which is 0.5. So again we would have the case that the DC gain has dropped by 1/2.
As mentioned, the limit here is to down-sample by 2. Clearly if we selected every 4th sample we see that we have the case of every coefficient in the resulting filter being 0! (or if we offset by 1 we no longer would have a symmetric low pass filter result).
The reason this works, and the extend to which it will work, is that we are following the rules of Nyquist: the filter coefficients is the time domain impulse response. We can represent that same time response exactly as long as we sample it at least twice the bandwidth as given by the cut-off of the frequency response for the low pass filter. (And in reality any response above the Nyquist rate which is half the sampling rate will alias causing some distortion in the realizable case). When down-sampling an arbitrary time domain waveform, there is no modification to the gain. The reason the DC gain of the filter (and therefore the passband since the filter response is only scaled but not otherwise changed) is modified when the time domain waveform is the impulse response of the filter, and we down-sample those coefficients, is because the DC gain is given by the sum of those coefficients.
Expanding on that explanation, consider an arbitrary continuous time function $x(t)$ such as that plotted below, and if properly sampled to $x[n]$ following the rules of Nyquist, then the samples given by $x[n]$ are sufficient to completely describe the waveform given by $x(t)$.

The DC gain of a filter is the integration of the time domain impulse response function (area under the curve), so as a discrete time approximation of integration this is given as
$$\int(x(t) \approx \Delta T \sum x[n]$$
If we were to select every other sample, and as long as we still met the Nyquist criteria to still represent the continuous time waveform, we would get the following result:
$$\int(x(t) \approx 2\Delta T \sum x[2n]$$
Where $x[2n]$ selects every other sample, and for the integration (total area) to match we need to multiply by the updated time step which would now be $2\Delta T$.
And generally:
$$\int(x(t) \approx D\Delta T \sum x[Dn]$$
And from this we see that the following is true for all cases in which we meet the Nyquist criteria:
$$\sum x[Dn] = \frac{1}{D} \sum x[n]$$
(And notably when we use time in units of samples at the down-sampled rate, $D\Delta T =1$).
Here is another example which also demonstrates the practical use of down-sampled filters for the creation of fractional delay filters.
Below are the coefficients for a 95 tap low pass FIR filter with a cutoff frequency of 0.08 cycles/sample (appropriate for down-sample up to 4:

The magnitude and group delay for the original filter and then the down-sampled filter (for all possible offsets when down-sampling by 4) is plotted below where for comparison the frequency and delay has been referred to the input (higher) rate of the filter.  This shows how we get the expected 12 dB reduction in gain in the passband, and also shows the effect of aliasing at the upper edge of the range in the group-delay results (and how for two of the choices we still have a linear phase result given the symmetry but for the other two it is not, yet still in the passband where the aliasing isn't pronounced, we do replicate the performance of the filter including linear phase over that region).

And notably if we plot the group delay at the output rate of the filter we see the utility here in using this approach to create fractional delay filters (which is also how polyphase filters operate).


It's equivalent to a 19-tap FIR filter if the first (0th) and last tap coefficients are zero.  But not a biggie.

@robertbristow-johnson yes! shame on me for not following the rule to have the filter order be even but not a multiple of 4!

Thank you. But I still don't get it. Why does the average have to be 1/D if decimated by D since the coefficients vary a lot?

@c119 I think I see your confusion and added further details - assuming you are comfortable with the Nyquist sampling criteria and what it means I think the additional explanation should clear it up for you.

Thank you very much.

Yes, of course.

Sorry, I can only mark one as answer. I think your answer is nice too and well illustrated.

@c1119 yes thanks for that. I was referring to the other questions you have asked since you joined, there are a bunch of answers and maybe some of those that others provided here are also worthy?
